# Javascript is not passing in the values into my php code to run

Tags: javascript, php

when i run the form and the sql using `action="addCustomer.php"` it works fine but when i am using the js the data is not passing through and i am not getting an error in the console and it says that it is picking up the variables in the timeline from the original page but the js is not? Can anyone see why?

I am using the following form:

```
  <form id="dataForm" method="GET">
  <div>
    <h2 id="formheader">Add Order Details:</h2>
    <label>First Name:</label>
    <input class="inputForm" id="inputFirstName" type="text" name="firstname">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Last Name:</label>
    <input class="inputForm" id="inputLastName"  type="text" name="lastname">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Address:  </label>
    <input class="inputForm" id="inputAdress" type="text" name="address">
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>Post Code:</label>
    <input class="inputForm" id="inputPostcode" type="text" name="postcode">
  </div>
  <div>
  <section class="inputForm">
  <label>Delievery Type:</label>
  <select name="deliverytype">
  <option ="3-5 Days">3-5 Days</option>
  <option ="Next Day">Next Day</option>
  </select> 
  </section> 
  <input type="hidden" id="calc" value="" name="calc">
  </div>
  <div id="theSubmit">
      <button id="checkoutButton">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

and the following bit of js:

```
function addCustomer(){
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var firstName = document.getElementById("inputFirstName").value;
  var lastName = document.getElementById("inputLastName").value;
  var address = document.getElementById("inputAdress").value;
  var postcode = document.getElementById("inputPostcode").value;
  var delievery = document.getElementById("deliverytype").value;
  if(firstName != "" && lastName != "" && address !="" && postcode !=""){
    var url = "addCustomer.php?FIRSTNAME=" + firstName + "&LASTNAME=" + lastName + "&ADDRESS=" + address + "&POST_CODE=" + postcode + "&DELIVERY_TYPE=" + delievery;

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, false);
    xmlhttp.send();
     }
   else{
    alert("enter Some Data");
   }
}

submitButton = document.getElementById("checkoutButton");
submitButton.addEventListener("click", addCustomer);
```

and the following php sql code:

```
$name = $_GET['firstname'];
     $lastname = $_GET['lastname'];
     $userAddress = $_GET['address'];
     $userPostCode = $_GET['postcode'];
     $delivery = $_GET['deliverytype'];
     $totalCost = $_GET['calc'];

     if($name !="" && $lastname !="" && $userAddress !="" && $userPostCode !="" ){
     $sql = "INSERT INTO USERS (FIRSTNAME, SECONDNAME, ADDRESS, POST_CODE, DELIVERY_TYPE) VALUES ('$name', '$lastname', '$userAddress', '$userPostCode', '$delivery') ";
     $conn->exec($sql);
     echo "worked";
     }
```

Comment: Why are you using capitalized versions of the parameter names when you build the URL?

Comment: It's like sql-injections' heaven.

Comment: Your `js` does not send the parameter `calc`.

Comment: At least use `mysql_real_escape_string` (or mysqli) http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Answer (score 1):

Try to send variables in lowercase:

```
var url = "addcustomer.php?firstname=" + firstName + "&lastname=" + lastName + "&address=" + address + "&post_code=" + postcode + "&delivery_type=" + delievery;
```

Any way you are just sending the variable any changes should happen in database not in console log of your browser
And PLEASE read about [SQL Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) ...

Comment: `js` is case sensitive... `firstname` etc will all be undefined (in the JS side) so the URL will be `addcustomer.php?firstname=&lastname=...`

Comment: @Rudu Mybad, I converted it to lowercase using online tools :D